# Can't SSH into server after adding KexAlgorithms and MACs to sshd_config

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

After appending the following lines to the end of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
```

And restarting ssh

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

I find myself unable to ssh into the instance anymore.

```
ssh -i xxxxx.pem -vvvv ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx                                                                                                            
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xx.xx.xx.xx  is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx  [xx.xx.xx.xx ] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xx.xx.xx.xx  port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx  port 22: Connection refused
```

Am I completely out of luck or do I still have a chance by specifying something specific with `-m`, `-oKexAlgorithms` when I try to use `ssh` from the client? This is out of my depth so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with another instance and I *think* that blindly appending those 2 lines to sshd_config like that resulted in an invalid config so when I restarted the ssh daemon, it failed to start so I would have been locked out.

Luckily, this was an EC2 instance which I could afford to stop and edit the instance's User Data so I could get Cloud Init to run some commands to restore the sshd_config using a backup file I had created before messing everything up.

E.g. User Data

```
#cloud-config
bootcmd:
 - cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config_bak /etc/ssh/sshd_config
 - /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Once, I verified that I was able to SSH in, I stopped the instance again, reverted the User Data (so it won't run those commands again the next time the instance boots) and restarted the instance.